# Why is View requiring using statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following in a view I created, but the `model.UserName` is not recognized:

```
@model AcmeMVC.Models.SelectUserRolesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Roles";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Roles for user @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)</h2>
```

If I add: `@using AcmeMVC.Models` it will work.

But, I have this entry in the `web.config` in my `Views` folder:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    .....
    <add namespace="AcmeMVC" />
    <add namespace="AcmeMVC.Models" />
    .....
```

I thought this would make it so I didn't need the `using` statement, but I still do.

Does anyone have any clue on what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this line

```
<h2>Roles for user @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)</h2>
```

So it is like this

```
<h2>Roles for user @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.UserName)</h2>
```

The `@model` is directive to indicate you want to use strongly-typed model classes within your view. It is not a reference to an instance of the object. To access the model in your `View` you can use an expression (i.e. `m=>m.Property`)

Comment: I'm actually really surprised that that fixed it. The use of "model" in the DisplayFor is not a reference to the directive, it's simply a context variable at that point. I do it that way all the time and have never run into this problem.